# Cooling of salt on a conveyor belt

Tags: temperature, cooling

Hi there and thanks in advance!

My name is Chris, I'm a chemist who's been put in charge of getting the boss's new salt plant running smoothly. He owns several small companies and I'm the closest thing to an engineer! But here is the basic setup I need help with:

We take wet salt, pass it through a 30 foot rotating tube furnace. Then it passes through a size screener, the large pieces go through a crusher and the smaller pieces move into a large hopper, which then loads the salt into a bagging machine and it's done. The salt has to dry in the furnace but cool down enough after the furnace to be bagged. The approximate temperatures are 200*F for drying and 160*F for bagging.

Here are some general questions that I would love some help/general equations for:

1. Given the furnace dimensions, what speed will the furnace have to rotate to move the salt at a certain speed?
2. Depending on the depth of the salt on the belt, approximately how fast can I expect the salt to cool related to atmospheric temperature? And what about in the large hopper? I imagine it will be quite insulated.

Comment: Hi Chris. This seems like more of a chemical engineering problem. I doubt many of us hereabouts have the experience to help with this sort of thing. It might be worth asking on the [Engineering Stack Exchange](http://engineering.stackexchange.com/), though I'm not sure whether they would cover this sort of thing.

Comment: Definitely not a physics stack exchange question and you can try but I doubt that engineering stack exchange will be able to help you much, either. Your questions depend too much on the detailed specifics of your particular setup. You will probably just have identify all of the tuning parameters available to you with your particular apparatus and run some tests on your own to determine the optimum settings for your needs.

Comment: @SamualWeir has it absolutely right: in engineering experiments are always preferable to theory. You guys must have done this for a long time, already, so you do know how it works. Any optimization has to be made locally with the available equipment and I am pretty sure that your setup would profit from a closed loop control mechanism. That can be one person at the end of the line taking samples once an hour or once a day and  adjusting the speed of the conveyor by hand or it can be a sophisticated industrial control... we can't tell you either way.